# Is buying iPhone apps like a subscription or a one time purchase?

Tags: applications, iphone, ios-appstore

I've got a couple of questions regarding buying iPhone apps.

1) If Fruit ninja is $0.99 does it mean that if I buy it i will have to pay $0.99 every year? or is it a one time payment (what other hidden payments are there?)

2) Is there anyway we can be tricked into buying something that is not what we thought it is.. like if i search for fruit ninja (or some other game) how big is the chance that there is a "con app" waiting for me to buy but isn't actually the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It's a one-off payment.

2) Apple don't allow duplicate app names in the store, so as long as you make sure that the name of the app you're buying *exactly* matches the name of the app that you want, then you should be OK. Or if it's a popular app, like Fruit Ninja, just buy it from the listing of most popular apps.

Comment: The only "hidden payment" that could be added is sales tax if your state requires it.

Comment: @NReilingh Good point, or country tax, like a VAT.

Comment: On duplicate names, Apple's very responsive to taking down clones when they're pointed out by the original developer, much more so than in the Android Market (where it can be nearly impossible to find the original of some apps).

Comment: Check the star rating and the user reviews before you buy.

Comment: If you want a little more due-diligence, check the developer name as well. It shouldn't be hard, with a Google search, to know who actually *made* the game. :)

Comment: And if you did buy a "con app", make sure you let Apple know. They'll take care of that and maybe even give you a refund. There is a "report a problem with my purchase" button somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few words of note:

It is possible for a developer to submit a major upgrade to an app (albeit with a different name) and require payment again. This was pretty common in the days before iOS - major updates required you to repurchase your app, point releases were free. Perhaps the most infamous case on iOS was when Tweetie 2 came out - users who had paid for Tweetie, even just days prior, were now expected to buy the app again if they wanted all the new features.

That being said, very few iOS developers do that, and will generally will make it very clear when a situation such as that arrises.

The other note is that some applications will offer in app subscriptions to content, specifically magazine applications. As far as I know it's not possible for regular apps to do so but I could be mistaken there. But, again, generally speaking this is for a specific type of app and you won't likely encounter it often.